# What is the inverse of $2^x$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse

*Note: This may not be correct mathematical term, so in case of confusion, I mean what division is to multiplication. If not, just poke me in the comments.*

I was given this the other day:

$2^x=8$

Which I solved as follows:

$2^x=2^3 \implies x=3$

What did I actually do to solve the equation?

Does this apply for other numbers and is there a general rule? I.e. $n^x$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: The inverse is known as the logarithm base $2$, written as $$\log_2(y)=x\iff 2^x=y$$

Comment: I like the way you phrased this question.

Comment: Note that while I think technically this is a duplicate (and therefore it would be good for it to be linked back to the earlier question and its good answers), I too like the phrasing of this question, in fact I like it better than the "original" question.

Comment: @DavidK this question is different in nature. It is asking how to interpret the way the OP solved $2^x = 2^3$. This doesn't necessarily mean they applied a logarithm (though clearly it's connected).

Comment: @Joel I think the question is explicitly how to generalize how the OP solved $2^x=8$ ("is there a general rule?"), and there are now several answers saying "logarithms." Also, "what division is to multiplication" is a way of saying "the inverse", so indeed both questions ask what is the inverse operation of exponentiation. I have already acknowledged a difference between the questions, however: I prefer the way it is asked here. (I upvoted it, in fact.) "Duplicate" does not mean "bad".

Comment: @Mutantoe: When you can arrive to $a^x=a^k$ as you did with 2 and 3, you may conclude $x=k$ because the exponential is 1-to-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you employed to conclude $x=3$ from $2^x = 2^3$ is called the injective property of the function $f(x)=2^x$.

A function is said to be injective (or 1-1) if $$f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b.$$

In the case of $f(x) = n^x$ for a fixed positive $n$ (except for $n=1$), the function is injective, so you can make the same conclusion. Thus $3^x = 27 \implies x=3$, $2^{x} = 1024 \implies x=10$ etc.

Functions that are injective, are invertible. This means that there is another function, $g$, whose domain is the range of the original function, $f$, for which $$g(f(x)) = x$$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.

The inverse function for the function $f(x) = n^x$ is called the logarithm of base $n$, $log_n(x)$. Note that $n$ does not have to be an integer, and a special base $e$ is associated with the natural logarithm: $\ln(x) = \log_e(x)$.

Thus $\log_2(2^x) = x$. We can use this to "solve" for $x$ in $2^x=8$:

$$2^x = 8$$
$$\log_2(2^x) = \log_2(8)$$
$$x = \log_2(2^3) = 3.$$

However, this is no different from using the injective property of $2^x$.

Comment: $n$ need not be an integer, but it does have a few other constraints. :-)

Comment: true enough. I forgot to mention it must be positive.

Answer (score 4):

$$x = \log_2 y \iff y = 2^x$$

The inverse is called the base two logarithm. In your case $2^x = 8 \iff x = \log_2 8 = \log_2 2^3 = 3$.

In general the inverse for $a^x$, where $a> 1$ is the base $a$ logarithm. So $y = a^x \iff x = \log_a y$.

Answer (score 2):

Those cases are easy to solve if you have something like the example you just gave. Look for how does logarithm and exponential functions work.

In other cases like $2^x=\pi$ that is more complicated to computate manually. By computate manually I mean by giving an explicit value in decimal notation. So look some info about exponential and logarithmic functions, there is a lot of material about that in the internet.

Answer (score 2):

As the exponential function is strictly growing, the equation $2^x=y$ has a single real solution in $x$ (for $y>0$), which is called the logarithm (in base $2$), denoted as $\log_2(y)$.

$$2^{\log_2(y)}=y.$$

The values of $2^x$ for increasing integers $x$ are $1,2,4,8,16,32\cdots$, and for negative integers, $\dfrac12,\dfrac14,\dfrac18\dfrac1{16}\cdots$, so for instance, $\log_2(8)=3$.

The logarithm can also be computed for other values of $y$. Consider $2^x=5$, and look at the first powers of $5$,

$$5,25,125,625,3125\cdots$$

As $5^3=125\approx128=2^7$, we have $5\approx2^{7/3}$ and
$$\log_2(5)\approx\frac73=2.333333\cdots$$

As you can check,
$$2^{7/3}=\sqrt[3]{2^7}=5.0396842\cdots\approx5.$$

By using larger powers, you could find that the precise value is

$$\log_2(5)=2.3219280\cdots$$

It is worth to note that the logarithms in some base can be used for problems in another. As

$$y=2^{\log_2(y)}=5^{\log_5(y)}=(2^{\log_2(5)})^{\log_5(y)}=2^{\log_2(5)\log_5(y)},$$
$$\log_5(y)=\frac{\log_2(y)}{\log_2(5)}.$$

The logarithms are precomputed in printed tables, or evaluated by electronic calculators. They are commonly computed for base $10$, denoted $\log_{10}$ or simply $\log$, and a strange based denoted as $e=2.718281828\cdots$, denoted $\log_e$ or $\ln$. But that's another story.